# umount doesn't work with device in C (but it works in Terminal)

Tags: c, linux, mount

I'm trying to unmount programmatically an USB drive (device `/dev/sdb1`). If I run in a Linux terminal `sudo umount /dev/sdb1` it works. However, if I `gcc` compile and run the following C snippet as `sudo`, it errors with `ERRNO 22 = EINVAL (Invalid argument)`.

This is the code:

```
#include "unistd.h"
#include "sys/mount.h"
#include "errno.h"

int main()
{
    int r = umount2("/dev/sdb1", MNT_FORCE);
    if (r != 0) return errno;
    else return 0;
}
```

The same applies for `umount()`. `MNT_FORCE` doesn't change anything.

The function works if I pass the mount point instead of device, yet [the documentation says it works with both](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mount_002dUnmount_002dRemount.html). I find this way more reliable than reading `/etc/mtab` to get the mount point and use that.

> Function: int umount2 (const char *file, int flags)
>
> Preliminary: | MT-Safe | AS-Safe | AC-Safe | See POSIX Safety Concepts.
>
> umount2 unmounts a filesystem.
>
> **You can identify the filesystem to unmount either by the device special file** that contains the filesystem or by the mount point. The effect is the same. Specify either as the string file.

What is wrong?

Comment: From TFM: the first argument should be the mount point, not the device entry. `man umount2`

Comment: Check what "man mount2" says on your system.

Comment: You should check your system's copy of the `umount2` man page, not a random one on the internet. Not every version of everything is going to have functions that behave identically. (We wouldn't need configure scripts, etc, if they did.)

Comment: The argument should be a `mount point` instead of `device special file` as a single file system can be mounted at multiple locations. (And this is the requirement since kernel 2.4)

Comment: And that `MNT_FORCE` flag is only supported on few file systems, cite the linux man page directly:  As  at  Linux 4.12, MNT_FORCE is supported only on the following filesystems: 9p (since Linux 2.6.16), ceph (since Linux 2.6.34), cifs (since Linux
              2.6.12), fuse (since Linux 2.6.16), lustre (since Linux 3.11), and NFS (since Linux 2.1.116)

Answer (score 0):

Give your mount_path. It should work.

```
 int r = umount2("/your_mount_path", MNT_FORCE);
```